# Is there a way to create a HTML element using an array of coordinates?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Say I have an array of 4 x/y co-ordinates

```
[{x: 10, y: 5}, {x:10, y:15}, {x:20, y:10}, {x:20, y:20}]
```

Is there a way to construct a HTML element, so that each of the four corners math the co-ordinates in the array?

I know this is possible using canvas, but I'm stuggling to work out how to go about doing this with HTML elements.

The array will always contain 4 sets of coordinates.
The final shape may be rotated or skewed, but will always be a "valid" shape which can be acheived using CSS transformations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you got it in form of `[topLeft, bottomLeft, topRight, BottomRight]` of the original rectangle, you can try recreate it like this:

```js
const obj1 = [{x: 10, y: 5}, {x:10, y:15}, {x:20, y:10}, {x:20, y:20}];
const obj2 = [{x: 40, y: 80}, {x: 10, y: 160}, {x: 120, y: 80}, {x: 90, y: 160}];
const obj3 = [{x: 200, y: 30}, {x: 150, y: 80}, {x: 250, y: 80}, {x: 200, y: 130}];

function render(obj) {
  const skewX = obj[1].x - obj[0].x;
  const skewY = obj[2].y - obj[0].y;
  let translateX = Math.min(...obj.map(t => t.x));
  let translateY = Math.min(...obj.map(t => t.y));
  if(skewX<0) translateX -= skewX;
  if(skewY<0) translateY -= skewY;
  const scaleX = Math.abs(obj[0].x - obj[2].x);
  const scaleY = Math.abs(obj[0].y - obj[1].y);
  const el = document.createElement('div');
  el.style.width = '1px';
  el.style.height = '1px';
  el.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
  el.style.transformOrigin = 'top left';
  el.style.transform = `matrix(${scaleX}, ${skewY}, ${skewX}, ${scaleY}, ${translateX}, ${translateY})`;
  document.body.appendChild(el);
}

render(obj1);
render(obj2);
render(obj3);
```

However, I will recommend you to not store the shapes as its vertices ***but*** as it's transformation matrix. (if it's possible, of course)

Answer (score -1):

If you're simply trying to draw shapes without the use of canvas, you could maybe draw SVG shapes by translating the coordinates in your object.

If you want to deform a div, best I can think off top of my head is to make use of CSS transform:matrix, but you'd need to figure out how to translate your x/y for each corner coordinates to scale/skew/translate parameters.

If you're not deforming a div, and simply creating a regular rectangular one, then you should be able to translate your x/y coordinates into top; left; width; height; CSS properties.

Answer (score -2):

Well, no. HTML is a tree-like structured DOM. Although, you can have a DOM with `position: absolute` (absolute to html) and `top: y; left: x`, but it does not have any advantage doing it this way, from my perspective.